# How to define Prop types for Lit Elements in Astro?

Tags: typescript, astrojs, lit

I have a lit component in astro:

```
import { html } from 'lit';
import { customElement, property } from "lit/decorators.js";
import { StyledTailwindElement } from '../shared/tailwind.element';
import style from "./test.component.scss?inline";

@customElement("text-input")
export class TextInput extends StyledTailwindElement(style) {

  @property({ type: String }) placeholder = '';
  @property({ type: String }) name = '';
  
  render() {
    return html`
      <input type="text" placeholder="${this.placeholder}" name="${this.name}"/>
    `;
  }
}
```

And

```
---
import { TextInput } from "../lit-tailwind/form/text-input.ts"

---

<TextInput name="exmaple"></TextInput>
```

And I'm getting:

[image]

```
Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'name' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)
(property) name: string
```

How can I get type-safety for lit elements? I tried to export `Props` from `text-input.ts`.

Comment: Did you find a way to suppress this error?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately looks like intellisense is not supported at the moment.

This is a recent answer from an official contributor regarding the topic:

> We don't support Lit components intellisense at the moment

About the possibility to have this feature available in the near future, looks like it is not a priority.

> In the near future I'd say it's quite unlikely unless someone
> contributes it It's a fair amount of work and we don't have that many
> Lit users in general

Following a link to the conversation in the officail astrojs discord channel.

https://discord.com/channels/830184174198718474/1166792409301123124/1171190200974704772

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35233061)